# 在《恰似你的溫柔》這首歌歌詞裡面，什麼是「浪花的手」？

Tags: meaning, poetry, lyrics

歌詞

> 但願那海風再起　
> 只為那浪花的手　
> 恰似你的溫柔

什麼是「浪花的手」？

我有初步研究過，似是指 海風 ，是只是為了掀起浪花的手，這海風，恰似是你的溫柔。但網上搜查，卻說浪花，恰似是你的溫柔。到底是海風還是浪花，並且加上「浪花的手」，是否有比較確切的意思？

The question in English is, what is "wave / tide bubble hand"? Or does it mean the wind, is like a hand that touches the wave to make bubbles, and the ocean wind is like your tenderness?  The articles I found online seem to suggest it is the tidal bubble that is your tenderness, not the ocean wind.

If we need to understand it from the context, the lyrics is:

```
恰似你的溫柔
作詞：梁弘志 作曲：梁弘志

某年某月的某一天　
就像一張破碎的臉　
難以開口道再見　
就讓一切走遠
這不是件容易的事　
我們卻都沒有哭泣　
讓它淡淡的來　
讓它好好的去
到如今年復一年　
我不能停止懷念　
懷念你 懷念從前　
但願那海風再起　
只為那浪花的手　
恰似你的溫柔
```

Comment: The beauty of a poem is ambiguity, which should not be placed on the table for anatomy.

Answer (score 3):

A rough translation would be:

I wish that the sea wind blows again, because it creates waves that have/are hands, which are like your tenderness.

It uses the figurative device 拟人 (personification), either waves are personified to a person who has hands, or directly to hands.

It's not "a hand that touches the wave to make bubbles", but waves that touch me like the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

My digestion/intepretation of the lyric:

但願那海風再起　
只為**想起你**那**輕撫**浪花的手

Wishing the wind blows (on my cheeks) again because it reminds me of (my cheeks) being touched by your tendering hand (**in the past**).

Answer (score 0):

但願那海風再起　
只為那浪花的手　
恰似你的溫柔

我希望海风再一次吹起。海风吹起的像你的手一样的浪花，让我想起以前握着你的手的时候，你的那一份温柔。

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the sentence uses a figure of speech - 比拟.

浪花的手, means the waves are touching you softly like a tender  woman's hand, which reminds "me" of "your" tenderness.

So my translation is: **I hope that the sea wind will blow again, as the waves are touching me as tenderly as you did.**

And I tried to rhyme:

**I wish the sea wind blows again**

**Just because the wave(under the wind) is like your tender hand.**

p.s. 为 should means "because" here.